# git worktree add fails when running from Python subprocess in a git hook

Tags: python, git

git worktree add fails when running from Python subprocess in a git hook

I've tried setting the cwd parameter for the subprocess, manually creating the directory, verifying if the directory exists (it exists but git worktree automatically deletes it on failure), or using shell=True. None changed the output.

Running 'git worktree add C:/Users/meh/Desktop/blah HEAD' in CMD/PowerShell works just fine.

The git directory path is 'C:/Users/meh/Desktop/blah'

```py
temp_directory_path = "C:/Users/meh/Desktop/blah/abc"
print(temp_directory_path)
print(os.path.exists(temp_directory_path))
print(os.access(temp_directory_path, os.W_OK))
worktree_add_result = subprocess.run(["git", "worktree", "add", temp_directory_path, commit], capture_output=True, text=True, cwd="C:/Users/meh/Desktop/blah")
if worktree_add_result.returncode != 0:
    print(worktree_add_result)
    print(os.path.exists(temp_directory_path))
    print(os.access(temp_directory_path, os.W_OK))
    exit(1000)
```

Result without manually created 'abc' directory:

```
C:/Users/meh/Desktop/blah/abc                                                        
False                                                                                                                                    
False                                                                                                                                    
CompletedProcess(args=['git', 'worktree', 'add', 'C:/Users/meh/Desktop/blah/abc', '
HEAD'], returncode=128, stdout='Preparing worktree (detached HEAD cbfef18)\n', stderr="fatal: Unable to create 'C:/Users/meh/Desktop/blah/abc/.git/index.lock': No such file or directory\n")
False
False
```

Result with manually created 'abc' directory:

```
C:/Users/meh/Desktop/blah/abc                                                      
True
True
CompletedProcess(args=['git', 'worktree', 'add', 'C:/Users/meh/Desktop/blah/abc', '
HEAD'], returncode=128, stdout='Preparing worktree (detached HEAD cbfef18)\n', stderr="fatal: Unable to create 'C:/Users/meh/Desktop/blah/abc/.git/index.lock': No such file or directory\n")
False
False
```

Expected result:

```
Preparing worktree (detached HEAD cbfef18)
HEAD is now at cbfef18 commit message
```

Comment: What `getcwd()` tells you?

Comment: Hold on, are you trying to create a workdir **inside** existing repository folder?! It should be outside of any existing Git repository.

Comment: @0andriy it's just for the sake of the example, it doesn't work in any directory

Comment: @0andriy getcwd() returns 'C:/Users/meh/Desktop/blah'

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Python issue but a Git issue. I am trying to run 'git worktree add' from a git hook named 'pre-commit'. On commit, the index.lock file is created first then my script is being run. 'git worktree add' cannot copy this file for some reason.